# Trying to find DOM elements matched by a CSS selector using firebug

Tags: css-selectors, firebug

Is it possible to enter a CSS selector into firebug and for it to highlight the corresponding element(s)? 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried simple "find"?  In win, with page source focused in Firebug Ctrl+f brings up the search dialog.  Enter your CSS class, search.  Lather..rinse..repeat.

Comment: css selectors are much more complicated than class labels.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. 
Go to the CSS panel in Firebug. 
On the right hand side, there is a console that lets you try selectors.  It will prompt you with "Try a selector....".  It displays all matches in the right hand window and lets you highlight them on hover.

link to firebug wiki: https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Elements_Side_Panel

Comment: I can't see this on CSS panel. do I have to enable it? Can I see in the middle of debugging JavaScript?

Comment: I'm using firebug 1.11.4, what version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The search box in Firebug aka **Firefox Inspector** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), as suggested by [Madbreaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/177920/madbreaks) in the question comments, really works with any complex CSS selection! It says "Search HTML" on the UI, which is a bit misleading, but matches CSS selectors, it's not just a simple text search.

[image: Firefox Inspector CSS selection]

Tested on FF v33.0